# Why MySQL not using index for join on single column (no where or group by)?

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, explain

Here's my query:

```
mysql> explain
    select * from
        (select * from ratings where project_id=1) as r
        left join article_name_id as a
            force index for join (idx_article_name)
            using(article_name);
```

Here's the output of EXPLAIN. Why won't it use the index for the join?

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+------------------+-------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys    | key         | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------+------------------+-------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL             | NULL        | NULL    | NULL |     1725 |             |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | a          | ALL  | idx_article_name | NULL        | NULL    | NULL | 20441326 |             |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ratings    | ref  | idx_project      | idx_project | 5       |      |     1724 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------+------------------+-------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
```

**Edit:**
Here's an updated query/explain based on suggestions so far. `idx_article_name_id` is an index on `article_name_id (article_name, article_id)`.

```
mysql> explain
    select r.*, a.article_id from
        ratings as r
        left join article_name_id as a
            force index for join (idx_article_name_id)
            using (article_name)
        where project_id=1;

+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------+-------------+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys       | key         | key_len | ref   | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------+-------------+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | ref  | idx_project         | idx_project | 5       | const |     1724 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL  | idx_article_name_id | NULL        | NULL    | NULL  | 20441326 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------+-------------+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

**And here's the schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `article_name_id` (
  `row_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `from_ts` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_ts` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`row_id`),
  KEY `idx_article_name` (`article_name`(191)),
  KEY `idx_article_name_id` (`article_name`(191),`article_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20268652 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: Getting rid of the derived table makes no difference.

Comment: @Drew I've added an example. Why is this unsurprising for a left join? Non-matching rows in the right table aren't needed, and it's much bigger than the left, so I would think the optimizer would use the index.

Comment: @Drew I added the schema. I'm now wondering if it's related to the index length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the optimizer is estimating the cost of the full table scan is *less* than the cost of using the index.

The `FORCE` keyword doesn't actually *force* the optimizer to use an index. It only tells the optimizer that the cost of a full table scan is very expensive.

Assuming that the specified index is not a *covering* index, the `*` in the SELECT list means MySQL is going to have to visit the pages in the underlying table to get the values of *all* the columns. Likely, the optimizer is estimating the number of rows that will be retrieved is a significant percentage of the rows in the table. The cost of using the index would be lower only if the query is retrieving a small subset of the rows. Otherwise, a full scan is going to be more efficient.

I suspect the derived table has an influence on the plan, MySQL doesn't know the distribution of values in the `article_name` column of that derived table.

If you are attempting to improve performance, adding an index hint is probably not the right solution.

Comment: Good catch with the *. I've updated my example so it suggests a covering index, but the optimizer still doesn't use it. If not an index, what would you recommend? The left table has ~2k rows and will match probably about 5k of the 20m rows in the right table. No reason to scan through all of those.

Comment: I see the updates to the question. The index is on only a *portion* of the `article_title` column. We are smart enough to recognize that if the whole strings are equal, then the first 191 characters will also be equal. The MySQL optimizer isn't that smart. I expect MySQL would use an index if we had one on the *entire* `article_title` column, and not just the leading characters.

Comment: Yes, the index length was the problem! InnoDB has a byte limit on indexes. My article_name column was utfmb4 so 256 characters were 1024 bytes, which is past the limit. Luckily, the actual data is limited to 256 bytes so converting from VARCHAR to VARBINARY solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of why prefix indexes (`article_name(191)`) are virtually useless.

Either shorten the definition of `article_name` to 191 or upgrade to 5.7 so that you can index the full string.

It is one of the tips in [*Rick's RoTs*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots).